# What is the origin of the ring of debris in inclined GSO orbits?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, debris

Both these illustrations of space debris show a ring shaped cloud of debris at GSO altitude, but with an inclination of about 15*. What is the source of these objects? The graveyard orbit for GSO satellites is usually described as coplanar with GSO but higher altitude.

[image]
https://www.nasa.gov/smallsat-institute/sst-soa/deorbit-systems

[image]
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323245224_Orbital_Diversity_for_Global_Navigation_Satellite_Systems

Comment: Do you have a reference somewhere that indicates those are debris?  The first image just links to the graphic with no context and in the second image the legend doesn't mention debris.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome ... sorry. Try now

Comment: [potentially relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graveyard_orbit)

Comment: To answer the question, satellites in geostationary orbits have to fight multiple perturbing influences, east-west perturbations primarily caused by tesseral harmonic terms in the Earth's gravity field, and north-south perturbations primarily caused by the Sun and Moon. (Note: The Sun contributes both gravitational and radiation pressure perturbations.) However, I agree that this question is a duplicate.